# Subsetting data over a range of dates for multi-year data

Tags: r

I have the following example data:

```
dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2004/01/01"), as.Date("2020/12/31"), "days"), each=4)
Animal_id <- rep(1:20, times=length(unique(dates)))
df <- data.frame(dates=dates, id=Animal_id)
df[,"Year"]<-format(df[,"dates"],"%Y")
df[,"Month"]<-format(df[,"dates"],"%m")
df[,"Day"]<-format(df[,"dates"],"%d")
```

I am trying to subset my data over a range of dates that correspond to a season- but each ID might have multiple years, so I want to make sure I am grabbing each year as well.

I would like to subset my data to contain all points between 1 July and 15 September.

```
summer.data<-subset(df,
                    (df$Month>=7& df$Day>=1)&(df$Month<="9" & d$Day<=15))
```

in the above method I miss out on the 16th- the end of the month. Previously I have done this using Julian's day but then I also miss a day in a year where there was a leap year- so I figured it would be easier to subset by month and day!

I probably missed something really silly, but I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't quite what you want, as it filters by julian date between 183 and 259, so that non-leap years include 9/16. :-(

```
df$norm = as.Date("1999-12-31") + lubridate::yday(dates)
subset(df,
       norm >= as.Date("2000-07-01"),
       norm <= as.Date("2000-09-15"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
summer.data<-subset(df,
                    (df$Month=="7"& df$Day>=1)| (df$Month==9& df$Day<=15)
                    |(df$Month%in%8))
```

I figured it out with the above- but if there is a more eloquent way of doing it I would love suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I've always used re-formatting of the date object to a month/day pairing to allow for checking ranges independent of the year. E.g.:

```
fd <- format(df$dates, format="%m-%d")  
summer.data <- df[fd >= "07-01" & fd <= "09-15",]
```

The counts check out then:

```
length(unique(summer.data$Year))
#[1] 17

table(summer.data$Month, summer.data$Day > 15)
    
#     FALSE TRUE
#  07  5100 5440
#  08  5100 5440
#  09  5100    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `dplyr`s `between` with years extracted from the current row gives the expected results

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df[between(ymd(df$dates), 
           ymd(paste0(df$Year, "-07-01")), 
           ymd(paste0(df$Year, "-09-15"))), ]
```